# Заменить препроцессором один метод на другой

Tags: c#, .net

Предположим, есть код, который использует внешнюю либу.

В новой версии либы у одного из методов пропала одна из перегрузок, но нужно, что бы код работал и там и там(со старой либой).

Да, можно сделать отдельный код для разных версий библиотек, но можно ли извратиться с препроцессором, что бы заменить все вызовы Method([какая-то интовая переменна]) на  Method([какая-то интовая переменна],0)

Comment: Поиск с заменой по всему проекту.

Comment: Может с рефлексией поработать: определять версию библиотеки или доступность устаревшего метода, ну и в зависимости от результата вызывать тот или иной метод?

Answer (score 1):

Раз интерфейс библиотеки меняется (а это, кстати, нехорошо), я бы обернул вызовы к ней в отдельный класс. В этом случае все изменения будут локальны и легко обозримы.

Препроцессора наподобие такого, как в C/C++, у C# нету. Вы можете написать свой, но мне кажется, что игра не стоит свеч.